# Compare an id to an array in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have array in while lets say its "while A",like this:

```
   myarr=array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {  
             $myarr[$kodetb]= $kuranggesek;
             echo "kodetb=".$kodetb."value=".$myarr[$kodetb]."<br>";
        }
```

And the result displays:

```
kodetb=TB201506114 value=7001500
kodetb=TB201602179 value=8204000
kodetb=TB201602186 value=200000
kodetb=TB201602321 value=3500000
kodetb=TB201602322 value=150000
kodetb=TB201602327 value=500000
```

And then I have another query in while let say this is "while B ":

```
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3))
        {    $kodetbori=$row3['kodetb']; //this is id of while B
             //What i am trying to accomplish is i want to check something like:             start loop array sintax
              if $kodetbori_in_while_B==$kodetb_in_while_A) 
              {
                  echo value of $myarr[$kodetb]in while A
              }
              end
        }
```

Please help.. thanks.

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to do something like a JOIN to see the elements in a second table that are also in the first table. Have you tried this?

Comment: i have tried but seems quite slow with the join

Comment: so you're asking if($myarr[$kodetb] == $kodetbori){
    echo $myarr[$kodetb];
}

and just store $kodetb global

Comment: Maybe you'll have to benchmark this, because linearly searching with two loops like this won't be very fast either.

Comment: hi juakali92 please answer it with looping syntax because thats include my question and i forget to wrote it so i edit my question

Comment: how does `$kodetb` get set? is it just a timestamp?

Comment: A sample of your database tables might help. MySql might just have the answer skipping all this PHP.